# Why is $((-8)^2)^{1/6} > 0 \text{ and } -2 = (-8)^{1/3}$?

Tags: paradoxes

Why is $((-8)^2)^{1/6} > 0 \text{ and } -2 = (-8)^{1/3}$?

Doesn't this contradict the exponentiation rule (power of power)?

Comment: Fractional powers of negative numbers do not behave as you might expect.  It is related to the complex logarithm

Comment: but $$(-8)^{2^{1/3}}$$ is a complex number

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  When you originally saw ${(-8)^2}^{1/6}$, the intention was $\left({(-8)^2}\right)^{1/6}$ rather than $(-8)^{\left(2^{1/6}\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

The exponent rule you are thinking of is $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$. This is only really valid for $x>0$. With some negative $x$, there are some values of $a,b$ where it happens to still be true. But in general, exponent rules do not apply when there is a negative base.

Also, $(-8)^{1/3}$ is not universally evaluated to $-2$ as you say. It depends on definitions of exponentiation. Sometimes such things (with a negative base) are left undefined because of this issue. Some computing software would evaluate $(-8)^{1/3}$ to be a certain non-real complex number in the first quadrant. Try entering `(-8)^(1/3)` into WolframAlpha for example, and see how it is not the same as `cuberoot(-8)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

Note that $\left(a^b \right)^c = a^{bc}$ requires that $a > 0$. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents):

> the identity
>
> $\left(b^{r}\right)^s = b^{r \cdot s}$
>
> cannot be extended consistently to cases where $b$ is a negative real number

Someone who knows about complex numbers more than I do can explain what happens in the case where $a < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for instance $x^{2/3}$. Since $2/3=4/6$, it sounds reasonable to say that $x^{2/3}=x^{4/6}$. However, if we let $x$ be any real number (positive or negative) and use the "power of power" rule freely, we get:

$x^{2/3}=(x^2)^\frac{1}{3}$ is defined for every $x$

$x^{2/3}=(x^{\frac{1}{3}})^2$ is defined for every $x$

$x^{4/6}=(x^4)^\frac{1}{6}$ is defined for every $x$

$x^{4/6}=(x^\frac{1}{6})^{4}$ is not defined for every $x$

Hence we should conclude $x^{2/3}\neq x^{4/6}$ since both functions are disagreeing. So we have to chose between saying the rule doesn't always apply and $x^{2/3}=x^{4/6}$ for all $x$ or we can say that it always apply and there are some $x$ for which $x^{2/3}\neq x^{4/6}$. Since the latter is not practical, we chose to restrict the use of the exponent rule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a branch cut discontinuity in the complex plane. If you consider the square root function, and the following series of "equalities":
$$1=1^2=\sqrt{1}\cdot\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{1\cdot 1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1, $$
where is the error? It occurs here: $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}\not=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}$. It comes down to this: you're approaching the branch cut discontinuity from two different directions, and you can't assume that the limiting values are equal.

Comment: I don't see any approaching?

Comment: Multiplying two complex numbers is equivalent to rotating one of them by the other (it can also scale depending on the moduli of the numbers). This can cause, as it does in this case, one of them to try to cross the branch cut discontinuity.